# Transform enumerated tags in lists

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2

The xml payload that has to be transformed:

```
<xml>
<invoice0>201762133</invoice0>
<invoice1>201730800</invoice1>
<invoice2>2016419446</invoice2>
<invoice3>2016388689</invoice3>
<numeroValorConta0>10208.32</numeroValorConta0>
<numeroValorConta1>10196.62</numeroValorConta1>
<numeroValorConta2>10196.62</numeroValorConta2>
<numeroValorConta3>10196.62</numeroValorConta3>
<statusFatura0>Aberto</statusFatura0>
<statusFatura1>Aberto</statusFatura1>
<statusFatura2>Fechado</statusFatura2>
<statusFatura3>Fechado</statusFatura3>
<date0>30/03/2017</date0>
<date1>28/02/2017</date1>
<date2>30/01/2017</date2>
<date3>30/12/2016</date3>
<invoiceAmmount>4</invoiceAmmount>
</xml>
```

EDIT: Thats how my new transformation looks like :

```
<xsl:transform exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="xml">
        <result>
             <xsl:for-each select=".">
                <list>
                <xsl:for-each select="*[matches(name(),'invoice[0-99]')]">
                    <invoiceNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </invoiceNumber>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="*[matches(name(),'numeroValorConta[0-99]')]">
                    <totalAmmount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </totalAmmount>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="*[matches(name(),'statusFatura[0-99]')]">
                    <statusInvoice>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </statusInvoice>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="*[matches(name(),'date[0-99]')]">
                    <dueDate>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </dueDate>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </list>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <invoiceAmmount>
                <xsl:value-of select="//invoiceAmmount"/>
            </invoiceAmmount>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

But it is returning one unique `<list>` with all the elements in it instead of N(invoices ammount) list's with the 4 informations of each in it.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the `for-each` your `invoiceN` element is the context node so you can change

```
                <invoiceNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[matches(name(),'invoice[position()]')]"/>
                </invoiceNumber>
```

to

```
               <invoiceNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </invoiceNumber>
```

The other elements are siblings of the context node so you can use e.g. `following-sibling::*[matches(name(),'numeroValorConta[0-99]')]` to select all those `numeroValorContaN` elements, I am not sure whether you want to `sum(following-sibling::*[matches(name(),'numeroValorConta[0-99]')])` all of them or output them separately as your use of `separator` seems to try.

If you are processing `invoiceN` in your `for-each` and want to find the corresponding `numeroValorContaN` then use e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="index" as="xs:string" select="replace(local-name(), '[^0-9]+', '')"/>

<totalAmount><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[local-name() = concat('numeroValorConta', $index)]"/></totalAmount>
```

So in the context of your original code you would use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="xml">
      <result>
          <xsl:for-each select="*[matches(local-name(), 'invoice[0-9]+')]">
              <list>
                   <invoiceNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </invoiceNumber>  
                    <xsl:variable name="index" as="xs:string" select="replace(local-name(), '[^0-9]+', '')"/>
                    <totalAmount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[local-name() = concat('numeroValorConta', $index)]"/>
                    </totalAmount>
              </list>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </result>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcoA

Comment: The idea was : if I have 3 invoices, i would show 3 of this :
      `<list>
            <invoiceNumber>number</invoiceNumber>
            <totalAmmount>ammount</totalAmmount>
            <statusInvoice>status</statusInvoice>
            <dueDate>date</dueDate>
      </list>`

Comment: @ThiagoMuniz, see whether the suggestion I have added helps, it might help you create the result you posted, I am still not sure why your code tries to select several elements and uses `separator`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for sharing your xsl knowledge, and if I may ask, is there any material you would recommend for studying xslt?